# How to keep run Python Program in Background on Raspberry Pi after terminate ssh

Tags: python, mysql, linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

i need to keep run my Python Program in Background on my Raspberry Pi after i close the ssh connection, Because i need to save Phidget information on a SQL DB
I try to do this with nohup but it seems that the python Program isn't even executed.
Because when I look into the MySql DB , after doing below there nothing inserted.
I type in :

```
    pi@raspi ~/MyProjekt $ sudo nohup python sensorReader.py &
    [1] 8580
```

and when i try to look if this process exist whit :

```
ps -A| grep 8580
```

it returns nothing.
So do i something wrong ?

How can i run the python program after close SSH Conneciton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an ssh connection issue, from what you say the program seems to execute and exit. Does your .py execute in an infinite loop? Else you shouldn't expect it to stay alive.

Then, about keeping a process alive after the parent has terminated (the shell in your case), nohup is the answer, that means ignore HUP signals (those sent by a terminating parent process).

The '&' just means 'execute in background'.

The cron solution is good if your program is meant to do something periodically, but if it should stay alive waiting for some event (like listening to a socket), I would prefer to create an init scritp, so that the program is run as a demon at boot time and only in the desired runlevels.

Comment: My python program has no loop. It is waiting for Phidget sensor values, and saves this informations on a MySQL Db on the same Raspberry.

Comment: Ok, in this case a cron job is maybe the best (and most simple) solution (see Nonnib answer), but you shouldn't expect to see your process pid when you `ps aux` because it seems very fast to execute and it won't be executing all the time, it will spawn at periodic times.

Comment: I've solved my problem with Screen. Just start a new Session with screen -S sessionXX, and detache the session with ctr+a => d , and i can terminate the SSH connection. But I nevertheless need crontab for some works. Thatswhy thx Marco and best Answer for you

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend running your python program in a cron reboot job.

To edit your root cronjobs use

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add the line

```
@reboot sudo python full_path/MyProjekt/sensorReader.py
```

Then reboot your pi with:

```
sudo reboot
```

And then confirm that your process is running:

```
ps -aux | grep python
```

Comment: The Idea is good, but it doesn't really work. The process seems running but the program doesn't write the Sensor information into the SQL DB. Any Idea ?

Comment: You should set up logging in your python script so that you can track what it's doing, since you don't have access to console output. You can pipe stdout and stderr to a file from your cron job by appending 2>&1 >> /tmp/mylogfile.log and see if you get something.